# Suppress continued float in Endfloat table/figure list

Tags: captions, endfloat

How can I suppress the listing of the second table here in the Endfloat table list?

I have `pseudo-code` here declaring a variable `table-list-entry`, but I don't think such a command exists. Is there any way to do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tablesfirst]{endfloat}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{continued}{#1~#2 (Cont.)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=continued}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Tier 1}
\label{plachit}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{posttable}{-1}%deincremeent the endfloat counter
\renewcommand\tableplace{}%don't show and endfloat marker in the main body
\renewcommand\table-list-entry{}%don't show and endfloat marker in the main body
\begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\caption{Tier 2}
\label{kisel1}
\end{table}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this is what you are after.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tablesfirst,nomarkers]{endfloat}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{continued}{#1~#2 (Cont.)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=continued}

\begin{document}

%\begingroup
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Tier 1}
\label{plachit}
\end{table}

%\addtocounter{posttable}{-1}%deincremeent the endfloat counter   %% why this?

\begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\caption[]{Tier 2}
\label{kisel1}
\end{table}
%\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I have used `nomarkers` to remove the table markers in the main body. Also to stop the repeated caption from appearing in the table of contents I have used the empty optional argument in repeated caption like `\caption[]{....caption...}`